# Unload Autodesk.SplitScreen extension

Tags: autodesk-forge

How do I reset the screen to 1 after loading the SplitScreen extension and having had split it into 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to unload it

```
function unloadSplitScreen() {
    let ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.SplitScreen');
    ext.unload();
}
```